# Firebase Java SDK - muliple ChildEventListeners queueing

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I am adding ChildEventListeners to multiple nodes in my realtime database. The nodes may or may not be nested. The problem I have is that if some of these nodes are changed simultaneously, the onChildChanged event handlers appear to be queueing. 
 I'm adding the event listeners to node_a,  node_b, node_c etc. in a loop at the same time, like this:

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(node).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

But if node_a changes before node_b, the onChildChanged handler for node_b is not fired until any processing being done for node_a is finished.

Is this the expected behaviour? I assumed they would fire in parallel.

Comment: Please add the code in which you are looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected.  There is a single thread that manages all the callbacks from changes to your database.  If you would like parallel handling, you'll have to pass the work off to other threads in order to free up the single thread that initially calls your listener.

Answer (score 0):

> if node_a changes before node_b, the onChildChanged handler for node_b is not fired until any processing being done for node_a is finished.

This is expected. Even when you attach a `ChildEventListener` the Firebase server sends all changes for the location (your `.getReference(node)`) to the client in one go. The SDK processes those changes and calls the relevant listener method(s), before it processes any other updates from the server.